# Is $\sqrt[6]{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21})$ and/or $\sqrt[4]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{25}})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

I need to check if $\sqrt[6]{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21})$ and/or $\sqrt[4]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{25}})$.

**For the first one:**

Assume $\sqrt[6]{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21})$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{3}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21})$. So $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21}): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{3})] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{3}) : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21}): \mathbb{Q}] = 8$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$, it follows that $6 \mid 8$, which is not true. Therefore $\sqrt[6]{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{21})$. Is this correct?

**For the second one:**

First let's denote $\omega := e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{25}}$ as the $25$-th root of unity.

I tried the same technique, but ended up with $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})] = 5$, since $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(25) = 20$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})] : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$, where $\varphi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). So the assumption $\sqrt[4]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ *might* be true, if i manage to find some irreducible $f \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})[X]$ with $f(\omega) = 0$ and $\deg(f) = 5$. All this seems far to complicated for this kind of question. (?)

It might be easier to express $\sqrt[4]{5}$ in terms of $\omega$, but i can't see how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof for the first question is good, and with a little more work the same idea can be used for the second one.

The maximal real subfield of $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} \Q(\omega)$ is $\Q(\omega + \omega^{-1})$ and $[\Q(\omega) : \Q(\omega + \omega^{-1})] = 2$ so $[\Q(\omega + \omega^{-1}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 10$.  Since we can choose $\sqrt[4]{5} \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\sqrt[4]{5} \in \Q(\omega)$, then $\sqrt[4]{5} \in \Q(\omega + \omega^{-1})$.  But $[\Q(\sqrt[4]{5}) : \Q] = 4 \nmid 10 = [\Q(\omega + \omega^{-1}) : \mathbb{Q}]$, so this is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt[4]5$ has a minimal polynomial $f(x) = x^4 - 5$. This polynomial does not split over $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]5)$. Consider its Galois closure $L$. Then $[L:K] = 2$ since $L = K(i)$. So $[L:\mathbb Q] = 8$. But $\mathbb Q(e^{2\pi i/25})$ is also a Galois extension over $\mathbb Q$, so if it contains $\sqrt[4]5$ it also contains $L$ but it cannot.

Comment: This is fine (+1). I just want to add a related argument that may save the day some other time. The extension $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/25})/\Bbb{Q}$ is not only Galois, but also **abelian**. This implies that all the subfields of $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/25})$ are themselves Galois extensions of the rationals. Because $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of5)$ is not Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$ it cannot be contained in **any** abelian Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. For example, no cyclotomic field will contain $\root4\of5$, or $\root3\of2$ etc.

Comment: Anyway, I approve of this (as well as the other answer). Judging from the post, the OP has not yet learned about Galois correspondence, and consequently cannot use the argument in my previous  comment yet. I predict that things will change in a few weeks time, and then this comment will make sense to them :-)